# callback function in transform stream node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, transform

Its a simple example of transform stream node js.

Code :

```
const { Transform } = require('stream');

const transtream = new Transform({
    transform(chunk, encoding, callback){
        this.push(chunk.toString().toUpperCase());
        callback()
    }
});

process.stdin.pipe(transtream).pipe(process.stdout);
```

This works fine:

```
Input: hi this is me
Output: HI THIS IS ME
Input: hi this is me again
Output: HI THIS IS ME AGAIN
```

Now if i do not call the callback function, this program does not works as before.

New code:

```
const { Transform } = require('stream');

const transtream = new Transform({
    transform(chunk, encoding, callback){
        this.push(chunk.toString().toUpperCase());
        //callback()
    }
});

process.stdin.pipe(transtream).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Now when i give input, it works for the first time, then it stops transforming the data. so no output 2nd input onwards.

```
Input: hi this is me
Output: HI THIS IS ME
Input: hi this is me again
Input: hey
```

Question: Why callback is needed? and why the program changes behavior when it is not called?

Comment: Are you asking why the callback is needed?

Comment: Could you clarify what the question is?

Comment: is it that the callback function pushes the data when it is being read as a stream?

Answer (score 3):

I'm simply copy pasting the some part of the docs of through2 npm module.

Usually when you whant to play with stream in node js it's better to use npm module.

The transformFunction must have the following signature: function (chunk, encoding, callback) {}. A minimal implementation should call the callback function to indicate that the transformation is done, even if that transformation means discarding the chunk.

To queue a new chunk, call this.push(chunk)—this can be called as many times as required before the callback() if you have multiple pieces to send on.

Alternatively, you may use callback(err, chunk) as shorthand for emitting a single chunk or an error.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it as how middlewares work in ExpressJS, if you do not provide a call to next() then the middleware does not hand over control to the next middleware in your ExpressJS program, that's the same way this callback function works. If you don't call the callback() method, it appears as though you have not transferred the control of that data chunk to the next stream handler in the pipeline.

If the callback() name is confusing, simply change it to next() so it gives you the same mental model as in ExpressJS.

There is no crime in using the native Stream Transforms as against through2, the only drawback is that your code may break if the underlying Node Stream API changes  which may not necessarily affect NPM modules.